# How to compare int values?

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-c++

I would like to know how to compare int values.

I would like to know that once I compare both 2 int values, I would like to know how far apart these 2 values are and if it is possible to put this in a 'if' statement.

The only problem I have is that (lets say int HELLO), HELLO's value always changes at random, so I would like to know how do I always compare HELLO's value and a different int's value on the go, so that at any moment if the result of both values are only 50 numbers off (negative or positive), it would trigger let's say timer2->Stop();.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you talking about - do you mean int as an integer value - because HELLO is pretty far for a int value (even on the extreme of reading it byte by byte)

Comment: I meant integer value. Deco answered my question anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Cool - not sure how useful your question is to future generations - going to leave that choice to another auditor

Comment: @AdrianCornish, 

The question is useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two int values, then you can subtract them to find out the difference between the two. Then in your if-test you just check if they are within 50 of each other and then execute the code...

Here's some pseudocode for you to work off of:

```
int valueOne = 100;
int valueTwo = 50;

int differenceBetweenValues = valueOne - valueTwo;

if ( (differenceBetweenValues >= 50) || (differenceBetweenValues >= -50) ) {
   timer2->Stop();
}
```

You could then make that as a function and pass your values in (as you've stated they're different each time).

Comment: I guess it wouldn't matter if let's say valueOne's value is always changing as it would catch it anyways? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between two `int` numbers is calculated as an absolute value of their difference:

```
int dist = abs(value1 - value2);
```

You can put it in an `if` statement or do anything you wish with the result:

```
if (abs(value1 - value2) > 50) ...
```